# Android Display Half Screen

Tags: android, display

On android , is it possible to create a opaque filter that displays only half the screen ? Think of it like a half screen advertisement in black allowing you to see only half the screen and working on a service i.e in the background.
Any code for this would be helpful as i am a bit clueless.

Comment: What do you mean? Like this: http://cdn.ilovefreesoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/G-Player-Floating-Video-for-Android.png ?

Comment: if thats not a widget then yes

Comment: i mean a static black rectangle covering half the screen at all times